# Comparing color contrast to choose final colors

Tags: flash, colors, actionscript-2, background-color, formula

I got some text that has a background, and the backgroud color can change to any color.

So, I need to find a way to figure if my text will be readable or not, the text should change to black (for example, yellow background) or white ( dark blue background ) if the contrast is not good enough.

So, is there a method to do this?, what would you use to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this color contrast tool: http://accessible-colors.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your color into the HSB space and inspect the brightness property (from 0 to 100, 0 is dark).

Edit: AS3 version hex2Hsb

```
public static function hex2Hsb(hex : Number) : Object {
    var rgb : Object = {r:(hex >> 16) & 0xFF, g:(hex >> 8) & 0xFF, b:hex & 0xFF};

    var hsb : Object = new Object();
    hsb["b"] = Math.max(rgb["r"], rgb["g"], rgb["b"]);
    var min : Number = Math.min(rgb["r"], rgb["g"], rgb["b"]);
    hsb["s"] = (hsb["b"] <= 0) ? 0 : Math.round(100 * (hsb["b"] - min) / hsb["b"]);
    hsb["b"] = Math.round((hsb["b"] / 255) * 100);

    hsb["h"] = 0;
    if ((rgb["r"] == rgb["g"]) && (rgb["g"] == rgb["b"])) {
    hsb["h"] = 0;
    } else if (rgb["r"] >= rgb["g"] && rgb["g"] >= rgb["b"]) {
    hsb["h"] = 60 * (rgb["g"] - rgb["b"]) / (rgb["r"] - rgb["b"]);
    } else if (rgb["g"] >= rgb["r"] && rgb["r"] >= rgb["b"]) {
    hsb["h"] = 60 + 60 * (rgb["g"] - rgb["r"]) / (rgb["g"] - rgb["b"]);
    } else if (rgb["g"] >= rgb["b"] && rgb["b"] >= rgb["r"]) {
    hsb["h"] = 120 + 60 * (rgb["b"] - rgb["r"]) / (rgb["g"] - rgb["r"]);
    } else if (rgb["b"] >= rgb["g"] && rgb["g"] >= rgb["r"]) {
    hsb["h"] = 180 + 60 * (rgb["b"] - rgb["g"]) / (rgb["b"] - rgb["r"]);
    } else if (rgb["b"] >= rgb["r"] && rgb["r"] >= rgb["g"]) {
    hsb["h"] = 240 + 60 * (rgb["r"] - rgb["g"]) / (rgb["b"] - rgb["g"]);
    } else if (rgb["r"] >= rgb["b"] && rgb["b"] >= rgb["g"]) {
    hsb["h"] = 300 + 60 * (rgb["r"] - rgb["b"]) / (rgb["r"] - rgb["g"]);
    } else {
    hsb["h"] = 0;
    }
    hsb["h"] = Math.round(hsb["h"]);

    return hsb;
}
```

Application:

```
var hsb : Number = ColorUtils.hex2Hsb(_textField.textColor);
_textField.backgroundColor = hsb["b"] > 50 ? 0 : 0xFFFFFF;
```

Comment: I dont understand, whats the brightness property in that object?

Comment: added application of hex2hsb.